# Configure a Raspberry Pi for wifi from an access point by USB wifi dongle

Tags: networking, wifi, linux

I'd like to be able to configure a Raspberry Pi to work as a wifi access point that loads an interface where users can choose the WiFi network to connect to. I've read the guides on how to make an access point, but I need the access point to load a webpage (once connected to the pi) that displays the current wifi networks and the option to connect the raspberry pi to that network. After I make the pi an access point, what else do I need program for this to be possible? Do I need to create my own web server (Apache) and code a webpage to configure the wifi networks?

I'm currently using Rasbian, and if you're interested in the use case for this, I plan on putting a few Raspberry Pi's around a location to send Bluetooth data to my servers (RSSI, UUID, etc). I'd like to be able to connect all these Pi's to the wifi network using my phone, tablet, etc.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to run a web server, this could be `apache` or `lighttpd` or `nginx` etc.
Some sort of server-side scripting, whether it be `PERL`, `PHP`, `Python` or etc.

You will need a dhcp server that is started when the Pi is acting as an AP, and stopped when it tries to connect to a wifi network.

You will also need `sudo` and configure the user that runs the webserver to be able to run certain sudo commands
The following things you will need to do with sudo

- Take down / bring up the wlan0 interface
- Change wifi configuration
- Start and stop the WiFi AP / DHCP Servers manually
- Change the configuration of wlan0 from DHCP to Static address

With all that setup, then you can start writing a page to do what you need.